# Can I send digits to an incoming twilio call with twiml?

Tags: twilio, dtmf

I have a twilio number that can process incoming calls with twiml. These incoming calls expect the recipient to press some digits after the call is connected.

If I were making an outgoing call, I could use the `sendDigits` attribute of a `<Dial>` tag. However, I can't figure out how to do this in response to an incoming call.

If I were receiving the call in a web client, I could use `connection.sendDigits`

Is there a way to do this in just twiml? Should I just play a recording file of various DTMF tones?

Edit: To clarify, I'm receiving calls from another automated system that expects additional numbers to be dialed after the call is connected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turns out the way to to do this is by using the `<Play>` twiml tag, which accepts a `digits` attribute.

```
<Play digits="94"></Play>
```

Comment: What if I want to hear the calling party's prompt or a real person before deciding to press some digits

Comment: This saved me a day of pain.